# 'ValueError: The initializer passed is not valid' when using tf.reshape and tf. transform

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to replace every tf.nn.depth_to_space and tf.nn.space_to_depth in my TensorFlow model, since TensorRT seems not to support these operations.

I write the above codes but get a value error.

```py
    def pixelshuffledown(self, x, block_size=2):
        with tf.variable_scope('pixelshuffledown'):
            batch=tf.shape(x)[0]
            height=tf.shape(x)[1]
            width=tf.shape(x)[2]
            depth=tf.shape(x)[3]
            reduced_height = height // block_size
            reduced_width = width // block_size
            out=tf.reshape(x, [batch, reduced_height, block_size, reduced_width, block_size, depth])
            out=tf.transpose(out, (0,1,3,2,4,5))
            out=tf.reshape(out, [batch, reduced_height, reduced_width, depth*block_size*block_size])
            return out

    def pixelshuffleup(self, x, block_size=2):
        with tf.variable_scope('pixelshuffleup'):
            batch=tf.shape(x)[0]
            height=tf.shape(x)[1]
            width=tf.shape(x)[2]
            depth=tf.shape(x)[3]
            batch_size = size[0]
            reduced_depth = depth // (block_size * block_size)             
            out = tf.reshape(x, [batch, width, height, block_size, block_size, reduced_depth] )     
            out = tf.transpose(out, (0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5))
            out = tf.reshape(out, [batch, width * block_size, height * block_size, reduced_depth])
            return out
```

Then an error happens on the next line of pixel shuffle:

```sh
ValueError: The initializer passed is not valid. It should be a callable with no arguments and the shape should not be provided or an instance of 'tf.keras.initializers.*' and 'shape' should be fully defined.
```

It seems to have a connection with batch size, which is `None`. I tried to set the batch size to -1 but the problem is still.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I edit these

```py
batch=tf.shape(x)[0]
height=tf.shape(x)[1]
width=tf.shape(x)[2]
depth=tf.shape(x)[3]
```

to

```py
batch=-1
_, height, width, depth = x.get_shape()
```

There is no more error.